# Access a BLOB column in SQLAlchemy as a stream

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Using Pyramid I try to respond with the content of a BLOB column. Unfortunately SQLAlchemy loads the content of the BLOB as a byte array into memory. Is there any way to access the BLOB as a stream?

My model looks like this:

```
class Image(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = deferred(Column(BLOB))
```

I try to access it in a Pyramid view like this

```
@view_config(route_name='myroute', request_method='GET')
def get_image(request: Request):
    image = DBSession.query(Image).get(1)

    resp = Response(content_type='image/jpeg')

    # in this line SQLAlchemy loads the full content
    resp.body = user.image.content

    return resp
```

Is there a way to put the BLOB into resp.app_iter?

Comment: I'm afraid it's only possible with Oracle - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/Lvabajze3z4